# I can only connect to port 22 of my Ubuntu PC from a Windows PC, how to open other ports for connection?

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I have a Ubuntu and Windows PC respectively, they are connected to a same local area network, here is the situation:

1. I can connect to any server programs running on my Windows PC from the Ubuntu.
2. I have uninstalled the `ufw` firewall and isssued `sudo iptalbes -F` command on Ubuntu.
3. When I run a server, let's say, a simple `python3 -m http.server 8000`, on Ubuntu, I can connect to it with `nc` command on the same machine, but when I connect to the Ubuntu with `telnet` command and `nc` in WSL2 from my Windows, things become strange, I can only connect to the port 22.
4. error message: connect failed

In summary, I can access the Ubuntu service on the machine itself, but can not from Windows.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated

Comment: what release of Ubuntu?  and why mention `telnet`?   That is a very *outdated* app/protocol that was abandoned as it didn't include encryption capabilities long ago (`ssh` replace it, ie. secure-shell)

Comment: @guiverc , As I said, ssh works and port 22 has no problem. I have a service(barriers) running on Ubuntu 22.04(LTS), its port number is 24800. I  can't connect to it from my Windows PC. And I found that other ports and service also can't be accessed from external machine.